# Why is (long)9223372036854665200d giving me 9223372036854665216?

Tags: java, casting, double, long-integer

I know about weird stuff with precision errors, but I can't fathom,

Why is `(long)9223372036854665200d` giving me `9223372036854665216` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`9223372036854665200d` is a constant of type `double`. However, `9223372036854665200` does not fit in a `double` without loss of precision. A `double` only has 52 bits of mantissa, whereas the number in question requires 63 bits to be represented exactly.

The nearest `double` to `9223372036854665200d` is the number whose mantissa equals `1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100` in binary and whose exponent is 63 (decimal). This number is none other than `9223372036854665216` (call it `U`).

If we decrease the mantissa one notch to `1.1...0011`, we get `9223372036854664192` (call it `L`).

The original number is between `L` and `U` and is much closer to `U` than it is to `L`

Finally, if you think that this truncation of the mantissa ought to result in a number that ends in a bunch of zeros, you're right. Only it happens in binary, not in decimal: `U` in base-16 is `0x7ffffffffffe5000` and `L` is `0x7ffffffffffe4c00`.

Comment: From your explanation, when we cast it to long we should get `9223372036854665000` and not `9223372036854665216` right?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't see how what you're saying follows from what I've said. I've expanded the answer anyhow.

Answer (score 16):

Because doubles don't have that much precision. Why are you doing such a strange thing? Change the d to l.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why I'm getting `9223372036854665216` instead of `9223372036854665000` after converting it to long..

Comment: @Pacerier 'Doubles don't have that much precision' explains it completely actually. A double has 53 bits of precision, which is 15.9 decimal digits, which is less than your number.

Answer (score 6):

`Doubles` have 52-53 bit precision, whereas a `long` has 64 bit precision (for integers only). The loss of precision in a double is used to represent the exponent, which allows a `double` to represent larger/smaller numbers than a `long` can.

Your number is 19 digits long, whereas a double can only store roughly 16 digits of (decimal) integer data. Thus the final number ends up being rounded.

Reference: [Double - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 5):

Because doubles have limited [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision).  Your constant has more significant digits than a double can keep track of, so it loses them.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that limited precision means that it is represented in decimal so is limited to 15 or 16 digits.  Actually it is represented in binary and limited to 53 bits of precision.  `double` takes the closest representable value.

```
double d = 9223372036854665200d;
System.out.println(d +" is actually\n" + new BigDecimal(d)+" so when cast to (long) is\n"+(long) d);
```

prints

```
9.2233720368546652E18 is actually 
9223372036854665216 so when cast to (long) is 
9223372036854665216
```