# why is the Double.parseDouble making 9999999999999999 to 10000000000000000?

Tags: java, double

why is the Double.parseDouble making `9999999999999999` to `10000000000000000` ?
For Example :

```
Double d =Double.parseDouble("9999999999999999");
String b= new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(d);
System.out.println(b);
```

IS Printing

```
10000000000000000
```

instead it has to show `9999999999999999` or `9999999999999999.00`

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: floating point arithmetic --- the greatest mystery of computer science since 1985

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`double` only has 15/16 digits of accuracy and when you give it a number it can't represent (which is most of the time, even 0.1 is not accurate) it takes the closest representable number.

If you want to represent `9999999999999999` exactly, you need to use BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("9999999999999999");
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(bd));
```

prints

```
9999999999999999
```

Very few real world problems need this accuracy because you can't measure anything this accurately anyway. i.e. to an error of 1 part per quintillion.

---

You can find the largest representable integer with

```
// search all the powers of 2 until  (x + 1) - x != 1
for (long l = 1; l > 0; l <<= 1) {
    double d0 = l;
    double d1 = l + 1;
    if (d1 - d0 != 1) {
        System.out.println("Cannot represent " + (l + 1) + " was " + d1);
        break;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Cannot represent 9007199254740993 was 9.007199254740992E15
```

The largest representable integer is 9007199254740992 as it needs one less bit (as its even)

Comment: It's far more helpful to use binary arithmetic when thinking about normal IEEE doubles than it is to use some sort of decimal approximation.

Comment: 9007199254740992 = 20000000000000 (hex) = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (bin)

Comment: @DonalFellows True, that's why I only consider powers of 2.

Answer (score 16):

The number `9999999999999999` is just above the precision limit of double-precision floating-point. In other words, the 53-bit mantissa is not able to hold `9999999999999999`.

So the result is that it is rounded to the nearest double-precision value - which is `10000000000000000`.

```
 9999999999999999 = 0x2386f26fc0ffff  // 54 significant bits needed
10000000000000000 = 0x2386f26fc10000  // 38 significant bits needed
```

Comment: +1: Precisely this. It takes _54_ bits to represent an unsigned 9999999999999999 and the largest value that will fit exactly in a standard double is 9007199254740991.

Comment: @DonalFellows Wouldn't it be an even number? If 9007199254740991 can be represented 9007199254740992 must be represented as well.

Comment: @Peter: 0x1fffffffffffff is an odd number that requires a minimum of 53 bits to represent. The number one larger requires 54 bits (or an exponent). Guess what that value is in decimal? :-)

Comment: Technically, you can represent any large integer that has no more than 53 significant bits (and does not overflow). So `2^128` is an integer that's representable as a `double`. But `9007199254740991` and `9007199254740992` are the last *consecutive* integers that are representable in double-precision.

Comment: @DonalFellows, 9007199254740991 + 1 is even so it only need 53-bit as the last bit (which is zero) can be implied. 9007199254740991 + 2 is odd and required 54-bits.

Comment: @Peter: But it pushes you into a domain where you no longer get exact conversion between double and 64-bit int. There is special treatment in the FP hardware for encoded integers, but that stops being used when the exponent is varied; the information that the number is (probably) integral is lost.

Comment: @DonalFellows I think we agree to a point.  You get an exact conversion from `long` to `double` and it will give you the original value for `9007199254740992`.  You can argue this is not the only possible `long` which could have been resulted in this `double`. i.e. its ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

`9999999999999999` requires 54 bits of mantissa in order to be represented exactly, and `double` only has 52. The number is therefore rounded to the nearest number that *can* be represented using a 52-bit mantissa. This number happens to be `10000000000000000`.

The reason `10000000000000000` requires fewer bits is that its binary representation ends in a lot of zeroes, and those zeroes can get represented by increasing the (binary) exponent.

For detailed explanation of a similar problem, see [Why is (long)9223372036854665200d giving me 9223372036854665216?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811112/why-is-long9223372036854665200d-giving-me-9223372036854665216/7811169#7811169)