# Why are these two variables equal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I declared two variables like this and tried to compare them like this

```
var x  = 9999999999999999;
var y  = 10000000000000000;
x == y //returns true
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: The question is rather "why is `9999999999999999` being rounded to `10000000000000000`" (check your JS console).

Comment: Yes, just reframed that as this. I observed the behaviour that you mentioned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t/7179733#7179733

Comment: And why : 0.3 - 0.1 = 0.19999999999999998

Comment: Worth reading: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: It helps you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t/7179733#7179733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

"Javascript doesn't have integers, only 64-bit floats - and you've ran out of floating-point precision."

[Why is 9999999999999999 converted to 10000000000000000 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429451/why-is-9999999999999999-converted-to-10000000000000000-in-javascript)

Thanks to the member Kos.