# Different code with the result on alert.

Tags: javascript, alert, bigint, console.log

if use big number in "alert" or "console.log" return bad result.
Example:

```
alert(999999999999999999);
```

Result:

```
1000000000000000000
```

But we dont have any problem on `alert(999999999999999);` or `alert(99999999999999999999999999999);`

Comment: Related: [What is JavaScript's Max Int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

Comment: If you check this answer to the question [How to check if a number is float or integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3885844/1960455) you can check if it is a _float_ or an _int_. As soon as it is a _float_ you would not get the _expected_ results anymore.

Comment: Find it,
Javascript doesn't have integers...

Source: [Why is 9999999999999999 converted to 10000000000000000 in JavaScript?][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429451/why-is-9999999999999999-converted-to-10000000000000000-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the maximum integer in js is 2<sup>53</sup> or `9007199254740992` (see the link *Jonathan Lonowski* mentioned: [What is JavaScript's Max Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/1960455)  )  every number that exceeds this limit is not an *integer* anymore but a *float*.

As you can only represent certain numbers using floats. The result of an input value that is larger then an integer would - most of the time - be an aproximated one. That's why you get those results when you `alert` or `console.log`.