# currency pipe angular does not display the right value

Tags: angular, pipe, currency

I have this code:

.TS

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

myPrice : number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myPrice = 99999999999999.9999;  
}
```

.HTML

```
<p>{{myPrice | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'1.4-4':'it'}}</p>
```

the result is 100.000.000.000.000,0000 €

I need to display precisely the value of the variable **myPrice**

It seems that the currency pipe does not work properly.

Is there some workaround that I can use?

Comment: It's not about currency pipe or Angular, it's about JavaScript: try console.log(99999999999999.9999) or Number.isSafeInteger(999999999999999999)

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429466/12914833

Answer (score 1):

You might be better using something like [bignumber.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) - there are limitations to native JavaScript number precision and size, and that library also handles formatting