# Large values in double variable showing different in a TextView

Tags: java, textview, double

In my app there are values like below:

```
double a = 999999999;
double b = 9999999999999999f;
double c = 9876543210987.654321f;
```

Not always but sometimes. When i try to show them in textview, their low value figures changes and show different number. I try many ways to show them in textview true but not successed.
Below is all my ways:

```
double a = 999999999;
double b = 9999999999999999f;
double c = 9876543210987.654321f;

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#");
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

tv.setText(
    String.format("a: %f" , a) + "\n" +
    String.format("b: %f" , b) + "\n" +
    String.format("c: %f" , c) + "\n" +
    "float to string a: " + Double.valueOf(a) + "\n" +
    "float to string b: " + Double.valueOf(b) + "\n" +
    "float to string c: " + Double.valueOf(c) + "\n" +
    "cast a: " + (long)a + "\n" +
    "cast b: " + (long)b + "\n" +
    "cast c: " + (long)c + "\n" +
    "math round a: " + Math.round(a) + "\n" +
    "math round b: " + Math.round(b) + "\n" +
    "math round c: " + Math.round(c) + "\n" +
    "big decimal a: " + new BigDecimal(a).toPlainString() + "\n" +
    "big decimal b: " + new BigDecimal(b).toPlainString() + "\n" +
    "big decimal c: " + new BigDecimal(c).toPlainString() + "\n" +
    "formatted a: " + formatter.format(a) + "\n" +
    "formatted b: " + formatter.format(b) + "\n" +
    "formatted c: " + formatter.format(c) + "\n"
);
```

And below is the output:

```
a: 999999999.000000
b: 10000000272564200.000000
c: 9876543635456.000000
float to string a: 9.99999999E8
float to string b: 1.0000000272564224E16
float to string c: 9.876543635456E12
cast a: 999999999
cast b: 10000000272564224
cast c: 9876543635456
math round a: 999999999
math round b: 10000000272564224
math round c: 9876543635456
big decimal a: 999999999
big decimal b: 10000000272564224
big decimal c: 9876543635456
formatted a: 999999999
formatted b: 10000000272564200
formatted c: 9876543635456
```

Comment: Why do you initialize `b` and `c` with `float` literals when they're `double` variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert to Strings first you can do as

```
    System.out.println("big decimal a: " + new BigDecimal("999999999"));
    System.out.println("big decimal b: " + new BigDecimal("9999999999999999"));
    System.out.println("big decimal c: " + new BigDecimal("9876543210987.654321"));
```

**output**

```
big decimal a: 999999999
big decimal b: 9999999999999999
big decimal c: 9876543210987.654321
```

**NB** - hard-coded for ease of reading

Comment: your code was worked but i tryed this one: ```Log.d("MESSAGE", "big decimal b: " + new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(b)));``` and output was: ```D/MESSAGE: big decimal b: 1.0E+16```

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907745/2310289)